# Javascript analysis tool that lists all callers of a function

Tags: javascript

Are there any tools that will show me a list of all functions that call a given function?  Perhaps there is a code coverage tool that can also output this information.

Comment: I hope you realize that this isn't possible in general, not only because of dynamicness but also because functions are first-class citizen, so at best you'd get a heueristic.

Comment: In wordpad you can use Search, in some iDEs you can bookmark all the places search will find that word.  That may be the best approach.

Comment: @James Black ... except that in JavaScript some important functions don't even have names, and some functions are constructed dynamically as the code runs.  It's not a static language and therefore not particularly amenable to static analysis. Dynamic tools like dynaTrace Ajax edition or the built-in tools in Chrome and Safari can provide some information.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

Unlike most languages, it isn't possible to write such a tool effectively in Javascript, since functions can (and frequently are) called by name or passed in variables.

It would be possible to find out when a function is called as you run your code, though.